# Is it possible to append a camera?

Tags: camera, append

Is it possible to append a camera from another Blend file? I have tried file > append > camera > camera and nothing happens.

Comment: You've appended the camera part of a camera object.  Try file > append > objects > camera

Comment: As batfinger mentioned you appended the Object Data, that is the information relative to the camera (like lens, clipping, presets, etc.) but not the camera object it self. With your method you could now add a new camera object and then afterwards go to the object data tab of the properties window and pick your appended camera data from the list. What you probably want is to append the object itself, that is with Append > Object

Comment: Thx batFINGER & Duarte. When I Append  > Object > the camera is not in the resulting list.

Comment: @batFinger & Duarte. I figured out that I name my cameras ".camera" to keep it at the top of the outliner. Apparently the "." at the beginning of the name was excluding it from the Append list entirely. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Append > object > and your camera should be in the list. Are you sure you haven't renamed the camera and are looking for the wrong name? I've appended many cameras this way. Can you post a blend?