# How to append cameras into another file with exact same locations

Tags: camera

I have 5 cameras set up, all in each different location, and angles. I tried appending these 5 cameras into another file, but the cameras when they appear in the viewport, are all in the same location pointing downwards in Z direction. How can I append these cameras from file to file, so they are situated as I have positioned them?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52801/is-it-possible-to-append-a-camera

Comment: I guess so, this is a duplicate question. You have to append the camera from the _Objects_ category. Or when you have multiple cameras, put them all in a collection and append that from the _Collections_ category.

Comment: OK, I saw it now. All solved by appending from the objects category. Kind regards.